# Removing transform & perspective from child. not() and re specifying doesn't work

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/98uo6h2e/2/

So I've made a perspective effect using the code below. I want to exclude .hello2 from adopting the transform and/or perspective effect using CSS only. How do I do this?

Already tried re-specifying transform & webkit to none/unset/initial in .hello nothing happened..

```
<table id="hello">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="hello2">
          <strong>Test</strong>
          <h2>Test2</h2>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


table#hello:not(.hello2) {
  -webkit-perspective-origin: center top;
  -webkit-perspective: 100;
}

tbody:not(.hello2) {
  transform: rotate3d(0.1, 0, 0, 40deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
}

.hello2 {
  -webkit-transform-origin: initial;
  -webkit-perspective-origin: initial;
  -webkit-perspective: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `:not` selector.

```css
table#hello:not(.hello2) {
    -webkit-perspective-origin: center top;
    -webkit-perspective: 100;
}
tbody:not(.hello2) {
    transform: rotate3d(0.1, 0, 0, 40deg); 
    -webkit-transform-origin: center top;
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it just breaks my code and unsets everything.

Comment: @Yaya adding your html would make it much easier for me to help you.

Comment: just added the html.